# How to find duplicates in a list of strings of server path names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dotnetzip

> I am trying to find duplicates in a list of strings of path names to the server:
> My paths will look like `\\UTIR\STORAGE\10-23-2015\DEPOSITS\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_1.pdf`
> I will have have to 50 of these that I need to check the end of the path `\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_1.pdf` to make sure there are no duplicates.

```
List<string> manypaths = (List<string>)TempData["temp"];
        var list= new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in manypaths)
        {
            if(list.Contains(item))
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

I am using dotnetzip library and I have tried ContainsEntry, Contains. And everything else i have found online. When I add these files to a zip file I get an error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.

```
using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
        {
            
            zip.AddFiles(list, @"\");

             
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

            zip.Save(output);
            return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip");

        }
```

Comment: why you want to check just the last of path?the whole path is not duplicated?

Comment: @Sajid it is throwing an error when there are duplicates. Depending on the fiile there might be a different name right in front of the last part of the path. But if the last part is the same it will through that duplicate error. SO my idea is to grab the last part of the path and then check that to see if there are duplicates while adding it to my zip file.

Comment: `HashSet` is likely a better choice than `List` for this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get distinct path by last part, you could use `group by` the last part and take the first element, Like the following code :

```
List<string> distinctFiles = files
    .GroupBy(x => x.Split(new char[] { '\\' }).Last())
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Or

```
List<string> distinctFiles = files
    .GroupBy(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

**For Test**:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>
{
    @"\\UTIR\STORAGE\10-23-2015\DEPOSITS\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_1.pdf",
    @"\\UTIR\STORAGE1\10-23-2015\DEPOSITS\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_1.pdf",
    @"\\UTIR\STORAGE\10-23-2015\DEPOSITS\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_11.pdf",
};
```

Note that, the first and the second are duplicated, in different path

**Result**

```
"\\UTIR\STORAGE\10-23-2015\DEPOSITS\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_1.pdf"
"\\UTIR\STORAGE\10-23-2015\DEPOSITS\123_DEPOSIT_10-23-2015_11.pdf"
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!! that is EXACTLY what I needed. LINQ is amazing i have to get better at it. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: What if two entries differed only by case (`a.pdf` and `b.pdf`)?

Comment: Keep in mind, with this answer, you lose a file from the zip. If that file contains different data, it's likely required and you need to disambiguate the names. See my answer for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily with LINQ.

```
manyPaths
  //.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '\\' }).Last()) // drop this
  .Select(x => x.ToLower())
  .Distinct()
  .ToList()
```

This will ensure the list has no duplicates. If you still get the error it might be something else.

EDIT

If you need duplicate filenames removed, but retain the full path. You're going to either lose files, or have to rename them (e.g. file.txt, 1file.txt, 2file.txt, etc.)

```
var fileGroups = manyPaths
        .Select(x => new { Path = x, Name = x.Split(new char[] { '\\' }).Last().ToLower() })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .ToList();


//TODO: init your zip

foreach(var group in fileGroups)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach(var file in group)
    {
        var newName = count > 0 ? count + group.Key : group.Key;
        //TODO: save your file to zip
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! Now I am getting an error saying the file paths doesn't exist when my program hits zip.Save(output).

Comment: drop the first select (split on \).... just take the full path. Should work unless you have similar filenames in separate folders and Ionic cares about that

Comment: so I think I need to just get rid of duplicates and leave the full path. Anyway to do that with LINQ?

Comment: I just tried that and now its not getting rid of the duplicates.

Comment: is there a way that I can just add a timestamp to the end of the file and that would make it unique no matter what?

Comment: Thanks for the help Sajid provided me with exactly what I needed! You guys are awesome!

Comment: Why `Split` rather than use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netcore-3.1 ?